# Lamest SO/SF/SU edit wars

Tags: discussion, edits, rollback-wars

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Who moderates the moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22654/who-moderates-the-moderators)

The discussion in Jeff's [The Great Edit Wars](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/#comment-15830) suggests SO has seen some edit/rollback-warring, and Jeff mentioned Wikipedia's [Lamest Edit Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lame_edit_wars) list.

I've actually not encountered any edit warring, but maybe a list of our experiences is useful data about what to avoid.  Are there any good candidates?  Or are we better off not showcasing this material?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22654/in-yur-matlab-shift-locking-ur-caps

Comment: I'd say that http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3530902/revisions is even lamer than the Matlab one... But hey, that's how I got three badges and 300+ rep, so I'm not complaining

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This was pretty lame](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2610224/revisions) (PS: Andreas would be me and it was partly (at the very least) my fault.. I apologize I had a bad day)

Comment: -1 for the cocky attitude in that thread and getting into a rollback war against 3 users.

Comment: @json this is a discussion about "report the lamest edit wars". Are we going to downvote all of self reports? In my opinion, if you downvote something in a "lamest" context, it's almost saying that you disagree that it's lame, no ? ;)

Comment: I say +1 for owning up to it and apologizing, and yes it was lame. (Though I'm generally in favor of excising the homework tag anyway. That said, I wouldn't go to war over it. :)

Comment: Sounds interesting.  I guess the thread was deleted?