# Is there a super moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I just wonder if there is a super moderator who moderates the moderators?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22654/187954

Comment: And this post might provide some insight as well for when things get out of hand: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151606/handling-calls-to-remove-a-moderator

Comment: It seems you're asking quite some questions which end up being duplicates. Please try to search a bit harder before asking. A lot of basic concepts of the site have been discussed before.

Comment: Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?

Answer (score 2):

There are employees of SE inc. that oversee the moderators and are able to deal with problems that even moderators are not able to deal with.  You can use the [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help) link at the bottom of the page if you need to contact an employee directly.

Comment: Ah, but who moderates the employees of SE?!   ;)

Comment: @Mike The community.  If, at the highest level, a company's actions are viewed as inappropriate by members of the community then they will leave, and the company will fail.  There is no mod of the internet to prevent people from driving their own sites into the ground.

Comment: But, then who moderates the community? :p

Comment: It's a circle of moderation!

Comment: @Servy can you delete your answer please , i want delete this question. as its not a really question.