# Why was "An Update to our Community and an Apology" originally deleted and can it be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions

For those voting to close this as a dupe, it's not a dupe, I'm looking for non-speculative answers (an official one) and more importantly I'm looking for it to be undeleted or at the very least an explanation as to why it can't be. I was also asking about what is being described as *vandalism* and why there was a divergence in the rules.

---

While writing [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389897/218388) I was perusing over previous posts by SO when they had handled things badly and while using the `deleted:1` filter I came across this post: [An Update to our Community and an Apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology)

For some reason it had been deleted which I found to be quite odd.

For those who can't see it or the history:

[image: deleted post]

I then custom mod flagged the post because I believe it shouldn't have been deleted and left a small note:

> Why was this deleted?

Which was subsequently marked as helpful and a reply was left:

> It was originally deleted by Sara, we don't know why. Users started to vote to undelete once she ceased to be staff and her vote could be overriden. We deleted it again to avoid that kind of vandalism

The implications of these actions are quite unsettling, especially since we're telling contributors that they're not allowed to delete their own contributions when they're protesting or just because they no longer want their contributions present. Seems like a strange precedent.

A few points:

- Why was this deleted?
- Can it be undeleted?
- What vandalism are we talking about here? Or, are we now saying that voting to undelete is vandalism?

---

Based on a quick look this doesn't seem like the only post deleted by Sara.

[This one from MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389908/2263631) was deleted too so while people are speculating that it's a legal reason, I would disagree and it comes across as historical revisionism a lot more to me now:

[image]

Deleted 2019-12-23 @ 17:32 and the MSO one was same date but 17:31.

Comment: I handled that flag... I now remember [previous speculation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341005/369802) that the post was cleaned up as part of the [legal agreement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340906/369802). Sorry, should've remembered that at the time of handling the flag. All I could find was an old message in our mod room about users overriding the staff vote there and us re-deleting it, I didn't see any reference to that post (and possible reason) there.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell really disappointing to see no official staff reply. Though, that is how they operate these days. *sweep it under the rug*.

Comment: @Script47 yeah, like I said, speculation. An official confirmation would be nice, though I'm not sure if one ever can be given as I also seem to remember rumors about the contents of the agreement being kept pretty secret.

Comment: How about **_we_** impose a code of conduct on SE staff? Like, numero uno, transparency, numero due, act in good faith, numero tres, we don't enjoy you being afraid of us, numero quattro, you allowed to crowdsurf on us only by our explicit consent, undsoweiter. Where had this policy been all this time? Let's make one. Let's unionize!

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I'll wait for a period of time and if nothing I will post another more direct question asking for an update on this policy specifically and enquiring why Sara can delete posts but not others. Based on my edit she deleted at least one other post which reflected badly on her.

Comment: Oh and as for your question about the word vandalism... Flag handling allows even less characters for explaining that commenting does... But yeah, going around voting to undelete stuff that as soon as a staff bit is gone and you suddenly can undelete stuff previously deleted by staff...  It's not ideal behavior at least. English is *not* my native language and this word fitted within the character limit, but call it whatever word you'd rather see used for "non-ideal behavior" ;)

Comment: The other one was an answer though, it's not bound to the same restrictions as deleting answered questions. As far as I know you can always delete your answer (maybe not if it's accepted, but I sincerely doubt this one ever was that?)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I appreciate the clarifications but I would disagree. People couldn't undelete because she was staff/mod. But surely if she leaves and once again the people vote to undelete that's fine? Or, what if people disagreed with her deletion in the first place? Are they never allowed to disagree with staff/mods? Especially in the current climate where even if you do ask they don't respond. If it was as simple as a legal requirement why not just say?  Why always a shroud of mystery?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell '*As far as I know you can always delete your answer*' - I think there is a distinction to be made when staff post a question/answer as opposed to others. Especially when it in their (at-the-time) official capacity. Even afterwards, it still has historical value. Imagine if Shog9, Tim, or Jon started deleting all their answers. You don't honestly believe SO would stay quiet?

Comment: Like I said, I seem to recall something about the exact details of the agreement not being made public. It's legal stuff, but if you confirm something then you're not keeping a thing secret anymore and making things public. As for not undeleting posts deleted by ex-mods/staff, that seems "common sense" to me. No one will be mod or staff forever, that doesn't mean every action they took should automatically be up for reversal just because the system no longer blocks you from doing so...

Comment: Disagreement is fine, when done properly, which "voting to undelete as soon as the system no longer blocks it" isn't. A meta post discussing undeletion (which could've been made while the system still blocked undelete votes by regular users) would've been.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell '*Disagreement is fine, when done properly, which "voting to undelete as soon as the system no longer blocks it" isn't.*' - Hard disagree. I don't think we'll see eye to eye on this issue. You tie peoples' hands and prevent them from being able to undelete or respond to their concerns and of course they're going to wait until they can do something about it.

Comment: @Script47 If this was deleted due to a legal agreement, as speculated, it would seem that it was deleted because Monica wanted it deleted, because it contained statements about her that were defamatory. Insisting on bringing defamatory statements back because *you* want transparency seems out of line to me. Let's focus on other things these days, please.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike I'm insisting on consistency and transparency and I'll continue to do so. I'm simply trying to hold them to the same standards they like to hold us. If we can't delete our contributions unilaterally because we signed away our rights even though they're doing so much to destroy what so many have contributed to build, I then want to know why then can do so or in this case Sara can do so. If it's simply to do with a legal agreement, then so be it, but they can tell us that.

Comment: @Script47 Legally, they may not even be permitted to. Really, let this one go, there's so much else to focus on now. Most of the people most closely involved in that situation are no longer with the company.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike '*there's so much else to focus on now*' - Like what? I no longer actively contribute on non-meta sites and it's clear that SO are not interested in actual advice on how to improve. Every time we have a controversy on these sites there's always a group of users who say "move on", "forget about it" etc. and then months later we're in the same spot again.

Comment: @Script47 I mean that I'd focus on the 'now' stuff like generative AI policies, data dumps, and overall direction of the site. If you see no hope there, well, then it's probably time to move on and stop using the site. Meta supports the network as a whole, if you're only interested in the meta part, what are you actually here for?

Comment: Without showing anything that is deleted, part of the answer is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/340906/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries#comment_1142060 - another part of the answer (explained by a different employee) is: Each employee has a job, the person assigned to make announcements changes from time to time, sometimes the community likes the announcement (and the OP (employee, singular) gets upvotes), sometimes the announcement is hated and there's a movement against the messenger - in this case subsequent *acceptable* announcements from this employee were also DV'd and more.

Comment: If the speculative answer is correct (and it probably is) then it is not legally possible for there to be an official answer

Comment: @OrangeDog or, it's just like the numerous other posts that SO chooses to ignore because it's inconvenient for them.

Answer (score 16):

Why was it deleted?

Well, we had [a chat about that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341005), and that lead to quite a lot of speculation, potentially implicating legal issues. My take? It was deleted because it either no longer represented the view of the company, or because further statements since then have rendered it obsolete, such as [this update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340906).

If it was legally-related, then that's perfectly reasonable too. But we can never really know why, unless Sara or another staff member tells us.

Should it be undeleted?

Ugh... Why? Why drum this stuff back up? I think we can all agree that that post is a monumental trainwreck, regardless of your position on the debacle surrounding it. I think it's best to let this one stay deleted, *especially* if it involves legal nonsense.

> What vandalism are we talking about here? Or, are we now saying that voting to undelete is vandalism?

What the moderator who handled that flag was likely trying to convey is that the post was deleted with moderator privileges, for one reason or another (again, we can only really guess). This makes the post unable to be undeleted by non-moderator users. In my opinion, the system should uphold that deletion as a moderator-cast one when the user who deleted it loses their diamond, as has happened in this case, but it doesn't. Instead, users can vote to undelete it. The "vandalism" here is the ability to override a moderator deletion. It's kind of a hole in the system.

I know relations between the community and the company are, once again, quite tense, but we don't need to revive *old* fires while we're being bathed in the bright light of the new ones.

Comment: '*Ugh... Why? Why drum this stuff back up?*' - It's transparency. It's one of other reasons that drew me to SO and kept me around. The fact that people own of to their mistakes and can be held accountable. As far as I can see, whenever the company has messed up, they've kept it public, look back at the MSO/MSE posts that they posted that were downvoted to oblivion, they still exist. Transparency and accountability.

Comment: @Script47 This just lends credence to the idea that it could've been legally-related. If all of those other posts are still up (some from the Monica era included) and yet this is the one (or two, as there's an MSO post you pointed out) that was deleted, then surely there's a reason beyond shame.

Comment: But until such time that it's confirmed, it could just as easily be seen as something more nefarious. Why is it so difficult for them to come out and say "We did it for legal reasons"? I also completely reject this: '*I know relations between the community and the company are, once again, quite tense, but we don't need to revive old fires while we're being bathed in the bright light of the new ones.*' - It's a nice sentiment but a tired one.

Comment: @Script47 because the legal settlement prevents either party from discussing it. They've both already confirmed that.

Comment: @OrangeDog no expiration time?

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack not usually, no

Comment: @OrangeDog so why not delete every post in relation to it? Why selectively choose only certain communications?

Comment: @Script47 Potentially because those posts/communications were the ones identified as specifically needing walked back?

Comment: @Spevacus or, that's just speculation and what SO wants people to assume?

Comment: @Script47 because legal actions are very specific. Monica would have identified those specific posts, and those are the only ones removed. On the flip side - if it's SO trying to hide all evidence of it, why selectively choose only certain communications?

Comment: @OrangeDog '*if it's SO trying to hide all evidence of it, why selectively choose only certain communications?*' - Who said SO is trying to hide all evidence? I'm suggesting that an employee was possibly abusing their power.

Answer (score 0):

While we don't keep a detailed record of what we did *exactly* (cause $deity, there's a lot to deal with) - I do believe as the moderator who made the final decision to delete - it was because it did no one any real good. There was a follow up post that covered later decisions and at this point, there was a lot of abuse flowing.

OP had an updated answer and honestly this wasn't doing much more than annoying people by its existence.

It's worth remembering that staff acting on the site are community too - even if their decisions are unpopular. As with the MSO post, there was a lot of that sort of things going on.

And honestly, it wasn't exactly a great post either. We *all* know to some extent the events around that post, and I don't think picking at scabs does much good.

It was an attempt at an apology that fell flat, people got annoyed, chaos ensued. There's all there is to the tale. I don't really think it's relevant to the current situation outside 'SE does inexplicably damaging things sometimes' which we are quite aware of already.

[See also](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341009/135565)

Also:

> The implications of these actions are quite unsettling, especially since we're telling contributors that they're not allowed to delete their own contributions when they're protesting or just because they no longer want their contributions present. Seems like a strange precedent.

You can't rage delete your posts without an alert to us, and potentially a suspension. If you want to do so, get in touch with support.

Comment: "It's worth remembering that staff acting on the site are community too" — I do have an answer in this thread. Following info in it you will find the comment that a staff member wrote to me: "_We do not ever delete posts at the requess of users. We are even less likely to take this kind of action than moderators, **because we are not members of the community**_."

Comment: I sense you want to defend them, in hopes that our working culture between each other (between staff and community I mean) sees improvement, or at least, it does not deteriorate, but in order to find your _correct_ stance, you need to assess the situation correctly. This staff member did explicitly express that they don't want community with us. That they see themselves as acting on these pages in a different function. When he says it, believe it. Factor it into your model of the world. So that it can help you make better decisions, and carry out more expedient actions.

Comment: If I can't take the moral high ground - and treat people with respect regardless of my own views of their actions, I shouldn't be doing this. We can see how expedient actions end up. Folks do realpolitik better then me, but if you're posting on meta, you're part of the folks I work to serve. If they don't appreciate that, it changes nothing at all.

Comment: Then instead of writing "It's worth remembering that staff acting on the site are community too", you should have written "_I, for one, think of staff acting on the site as members of community too (even if they themselves may express otherwise). I advise y'all to take a similar stance, as I believe in its moral nobility, and I trust better outcomes from it._"

Comment: That's a lot of words for the same thing. I ain't a lawyer I just shepherd a few websites

Comment: 1.) as my previous comments demonstrate, that's not the same thing 2.) exactly, in your role of a shepherd, you owe us not to mislead us. On these grounds you are expected to strive for truthful accuracy.

Comment: '*it was because it did no one any real good*', '*OP had an updated answer and honestly this wasn't doing much more than annoying people by its existence.*', none of these seem like good reasons for it to be deleted. It's part of the historical record and should be kept there. '*It's worth remembering that staff acting on the site are community too*' - As such, hold them to the same level as us. Why are we acting as though there isn't a method of disasocating with posts? Why decide to straight delete? '*and I don't think picking at scabs does much good.*' - It's about accountability.

Comment: You're neither the aggrieved party not someone directly involved... So how's anyone accountable to you specifically?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek As a mod, is that seriously your response? You know better than that. Since when has that been the criteria on these sites? We see something wrong, we try to fix it. Simple. Whether that's editing a post that's not ours, voting to close/reopen questions that aren't ours, voting to delete posts that aren't ours, flagging posts/comments that have issues with them that aren't ours, and in this case, raising questions around Staff/Mod actions on posts that aren't ours.

Comment: It's a very reasonable response from my point of view. What do you intend to fix you can't fix otherwise?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek an understanding of why it was deleted instead of dissociated? Because from my perspective if SO has changed their policy on content deletion then I for one - and I'm sure others - would want to know. And if they haven't I want to know why the change in procedure in this case because otherwise it seems very much like a case of *rules for thee not for me*.

Comment: When Sara made those posts, she was acting as an executive of the company. They were official statements of the company’s position. She shouldn’t get to pretend that she never made those statements. Yes, I understand wanting to be nice and sweeping it under the rug because she messed up publicly and it’s uncomfortable for her, but too bad. She wasn’t just chatting as a community member. It’s wrong to erase parts of everyone’s history because she’s embarrassed by the part she played in it. It should be disassociated, not deleted.

Comment: @ColleenV What if Monica requested that it be removed? Remember that the statements Sara made were a central part of Monica's legal complaint. I think you're likely attributing the wrong cause for the deletion (Sara's embarrassment, rather than Monica's wish to not be defamed). The company can't discuss it now, without violating their legal agreement with Monica.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike It is [still available on the archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20191222000507/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology). If it was for legal reasons, they'd need to take that down and probably redact the deleted version that a good portion of us can still see. It could be redacted to remove the lie that Monica repeatedly violated the CoC so that the community's response to that statement could be preserved. History is important for communities.

Comment: I have nothing for respect for Monica, but I don't think she should be able to insist the entire thread be deleted. She is absolutely entitled to have the defamatory statements redacted or edited out though.

Comment: @ColleenV StackExchange doesn't own or have control of archive.org. They can choose what's available on this website, the one they own, and that's what Monica and her legal team could compel them to affect. If the legal team asked for it to be redacted rather than merely deleted, they could have done so; Monica certainly knows how the site works.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike You'd be surprised how much content is removed by request. They could absolutely get it taken down, especially if there are lawyers involved. I'm not going to speculate about the terms, but I don't believe for one second that the company was obligated for this specific action. Deletion was just the most expedient action.

Comment: There are comments on that post with thousands of upvotes that aren't preserved on archive.org. There are answers and comments there that provide insight into the SE community and how to best communicate with them. I wonder if we would be in this current situation if the current management had read some of the discussion there and thought about how to act on it. I felt like Teresa Dietrich did that, although I may not have agreed with every jot and tittle of her response to it.

Answer (score -7):

> The implications of these actions are quite unsettling, especially since we're telling contributors that they're not allowed to delete their own contributions when they're protesting or just because they no longer want their contributions present.

[Here is an example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366334) of how that can look.

Note that it is reported to had happened on the [Interpersonal Skills SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) site, which might involve posting highly personal information.

Users relation to their posts on interpersonal.SE is in massive contrast to how it works e.g. on Stack Overflow.

A [staff member's (not mod, staff) comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366334/how-can-one-report-a-moderator/366338#comment1220564_366334) is as follows:

> I understand that your situation is frustrating but removing all of the content from the question other than a single sentence overview is not what you're describing here when you say that you proposed an alternative edit. You removed nearly 8000 characters from the question.

The user pleaded:

> the alternative edit I proposed (privately to mods) was about a paragraph and included the overall synopsis without so many details. If you're on their mod team, I would like to come up with a reasonable edit.

but remained ignored by the staff member.

---

The [only visible answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366335) has +17/-1 votes: +16

It lectures the complainant without any compassion at all:

> Note that vandalism is not allowed because when you post on SE, you license SE to distribute said content.

and

> vandalising your own posts, complaining when moderators enforce SE's policies, and then accusing them of antagonizing you because of your missteps isn't a good way to accomplish what you want

and

> vandalising your entire post isn't the right way to go about it

---

As it happens, I submitted an answer to this post, that later was deleted by other users. I also have received a comment from *another staff member*.

As it is not visible for many of you, I quote the other staff member's comment:

> We do not ever delete posts at the requess of users. We are even less likely to take this kind of action than moderators, because we are not members of the community. Please do not point people to us as an avenue for deletion - we already reject these requests on a daily basis.

---

Update / clarification:

With this post, I wanted to provide substance to OP's observation: it's noteworthy that SE makes users suffer impacts like what I introduced, while they exempt themselves from similar treatment.

I am in support of the notion that SE also should adhere to some **code of conduct that is specific to their mission**, and that satisfies the needs of the community, especially in regards of transparency, accountability, and respect.

In such a code of conduct, I also would like to see special provisions aimed at maintaining an environment that is not harmful for

- neither the participating individuals (e.g. in ways demonstrated above in this post),
- nor for the broad readership of these sites (through distribution of disinformation (in the form of under-curated AI content)).

Comment: If you don't want it to be on the internet, don't put it on the internet, and definitely don't put on the internet in a place where other people can and do want to keep it. That's the deal every single user makes when they post anything. What compassion exactly are you expecting when the conflict is inherently insoluble because both parties want the opposite outcome?

Comment: @Nij "the conflict is inherently insoluble because both parties want the opposite outcome" — this is very much soluble when we have even a nano-gram of compassion for others. For each other. Even, you could feel mere respect for the other user, as they are, as members of this same community, are moving along the same course of development as you did. It's about letting the human in you to manifest itself in your perception.

Comment: What you've just said is gibberish and does not address my comment. The user wants to delete, the company will not. How does your compassion resolve this when neither party will change their position?

Comment: @Nij you are not the company. You are a moderator, and a community member. I expect, even as a moderator, you are allowed to rely on, to make room for your own judgement. Especially because as a mod you are not getting paid. You might have an agreement with the company, but you are not an employee. Thus, I believe they have no way to coerce you into carrying out actions against your own conscience. You are allowed to draw your boundaries, and say, hey, that's cruelty, if and when you feel that way. As long as we are humans, we have agency. Excercise it.

Comment: I don't understand what this post has to do with the question that was asked here, nor what point it is making generally. Are you just complaining that you've been unable to mass-delete your content? That's not how the contributor license works here.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike that was not my content, the case involves another user, who I attempted to help with an answer on their plea. And with this post, I wanted to provide substance to OP's observation: it's noteworthy that SE makes users suffer what I introduced, while they exempt themselves from similar treatment. I am in support of the notion that SE also should adhere to some code of conduct, that is specific to their mission, and that satisfies the needs of the community, especially in regards of transparency, trustworthiness, dignity, and respect.

Comment: The policy isn't intended to make people "suffer". It's because the attitude of "I'm upset, so I'm going to ragequit" isn't conducive to building a knowledge base. As long as content is considered to be *useful*, it isn't removed, except under exceptional cases. That starts to break down a bit on Meta sites, and definitely when they're official statements from staff, and even more so when there are legal issues involved. You're arguing about something completely different and irrelevant.